# Image rotation in 3D space around Y axis

Tags: java, image, graphics, java-3d, image-rotation

I have a BufferedImage and I want to rotate the image (Picture) around the Y axis in Java with theta angle not affine transform. The rotation will be like the image below (the rectangle will be an image).

I can do this by rotating each pixel of the image and drawing the image. Because I have to rotate a lot of images, I don't think this is the best idea.

How I will do this transformation?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you'll want to find the inverse transform from your output pixel space into the input pixel's space. You then iterate over the output pixels, transforming them into the input space and sampling the input image. The [Wikipedia entry on Perspective Projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_projection#Perspective_projection) shows how to make a rotation matrix for the Y axis. If all you're doing is rotating around the Y axis, you can simply reverse the angle to get the inverse transformation (assuming your image is centered at the origin).